# Why is the max value not being returned?

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 =[ '100', '5', '2', '30', '4'];

var i=0;
var high=0;

while(i<array1.length)
{

    if(high <= array1[i])
    {
     high = array1[i];
    }

    i++;
}

console.log(high);
```

Comment: Strings and numbers are different animals, and compare using different rules.

Comment: So, use `array1 = [100, 5, 2, 30, 4]`;

Comment: Why did this question get so many downvotes? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array of Strings, so when you are doing

```
high <= array1[i]
```

You are actually comparing Strings and not Numbers

Change the declaration to something like this:

```
var array1 = [100, 5, 2, 30, 4];
```

Comment: Or he could do this: `high <= parseInt(array1[i])`